# Userform selected control

Tags: vba, excel

If you look at the pictures I want the white TextBox to be selected instead of the "Doorgaan" CommandButton. This is an userform. Does anyone know how I can change this?

How i want it :

[image: How i want it]

How it is:

[image: How it is]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how you want it to interact with the user, you can set different things.

If you don't want user to be able to <kbd>Tab</kbd> there then make the button property **`TabStop`** to **False**, otherwise change the order of the Tab by the property **`TabIndex`**.

Note you can manually "Activate" a control by the **`.SetFocus`** method in your code to make it the current activated control. e.g. `TextBox1.SetFocus`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the properties `TabIndex = 0` for the Button and `1` for the TextBox. By default the control with the least TabIndex will have the focus. Just set `TabIndex = 0` for the TextBox.